# how to count number of occurrence of each words in a string in r language

Tags: r, string, count

i have content in pdf file (extract from a newspaper paragraph) like for example a news title - " this is one of the fastest and one of the growing sector.". Now i  want some procedure or something that count number of words in string. So when i run it the result should be like :

**number of time the word occur**   ---------               **word**

[1] this
[1] is
[2] one
[2] of
[2] the

and so on.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: `?stringi::stri_count_words`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this example:

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

s <- " this is one of the fastest and one of the growing sector."

 ss <- data.frame(x=unlist( str_split(s, " ")))

 sss <- setDT(ss)[, .(freq = .N), x]

sss:

         x freq
 1:            1
 2:    this    1
 3:      is    1
 4:     one    2
 5:      of    2
 6:     the    2
 7: fastest    1
 8:     and    1
 9: growing    1
10: sector.    1
```

Note you can use str_split to remove punctuation beforehand also:

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", s)
```